# For each integer $n \ge 2$, If $p$ is the largest integer such that $(n!)^p | 2016!$, find the minimum of $n+p$.

Tags: number-theory

For each integer $n \ge 2$, If $p$ is the largest integer such that $(n!)^p | 2016!$, find the minimum of $n+p$.

My intuition tells that $n=1008$ and as $(n!)^2|(2n)!$ so, $p=2$..

Am I correct?

Comment: No, you can find smaller $n$ such that $p = 2$. (And you can find $n$ for which $n + p$ is even smaller for larger $p$.)

Comment: How can you devise such a procedure?